# Physiological mapping of frustration

Tags: neuroscience, learning, emotion, physiology

What physiological changes are seen in the brain when a person is experiencing frustration? What effects do these changes have on learning?

**Optional background:**
I'm trying to figure out an exploration schedule (exploration = increasing the noise in the action selection neural population) for [Hierarchical Reinforcement Learning](https://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2014/papers/221/paper221.pdf) and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to base it biologically.